# React Native: Get Duration of local video

Tags: react-native, video, duration, react-native-image-picker

I am currently using react-native-image-picker to allow a user to select a video from their gallery. I am trying to disallow them from uploading a video that is greater than 'X' number of seconds. Is there anyway to programmatically retrieve the duration of the video, or is there another library that can be used to select videos from the camera roll that will provide all the information for the media object as well?